# How to update Column related to Row Number

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Is there any easy way to update Column by Row number not a PK 
ex:

```
UPDATE contact m
SET    ContactNumber = sub.rn + 500
FROM  (SELECT Id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS rn FROM contact) sub
WHERE  m.Id = sub.Id;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
UPDATE contact
SET ContactNumber = (@rownum := 1 + @rownum) + 500
WHERE 0 = (@rownum:=0)
-- for a given client, for example, Client_Id=123, use
-- WHERE Client_Id = 123 + (@rownum:=0)
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: that works perfectly with simple code 

Answer (score 8):

The syntax for using joins in `UPDATE` in MySQL and MariaDB is:  `UPDATE a JOIN b ON  ... SET ... WHERE ... ;`. The syntax you used `UPDATE .. SET ... FROM ... WHERE ... ;` is used in SQL Server.

For recent versions of MariaDB that have window/ranking functions, the following will work:

```
UPDATE
    contact AS m
  JOIN
    ( SELECT Id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS rn 
      FROM contact
    ) AS sub
  ON  m.Id = sub.Id
SET
    m.ContactNumber = sub.rn + 500
 ;
```

Tested in **[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=95be9cc63db56abd8eed2bbe10bc753a)**

Comment: actually both answers works for Mysql and i think first answer easier and simple than self join, thank you 

Comment: @MokhAkh both answers? I only provided one.

Comment: i mean answer from Akina above ;)

Comment: Yes, Akina's answer is simpler. It uses non-standard SQL (variables and ORDER BY in UPDATE) but it will probably perform better than mine. It's also easier to break (in an upgrade) and stop working unexpectedly, so you have to keep some tests around it.

Comment: in my case, I had to add the userid(primary key) of the respective row, back to the lastname. m.ContactNumber = concat(lastname, sub.userID) worked for

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer :)

```
UPDATE contact m
join 
(
   SELECT Id, @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum FROM contact
   CROSS JOIN (select @rownum := 0) rn
   order by contact.Id
) as sub on sub.Id= m.Id 
set m.ContactNumber = sub.rownum + 500
where m.Client_Id=1
```